# ServiceStack - use customized registration?

Tags: servicestack, registration

i created a customized user table for authentication purpose. When i tried to register an user, the built-in registerservice.cs went to UserAuth so a

```
""ResponseStatus": {
    "ErrorCode": "InvalidCastException",
    "Message": "Unable to cast object of type 'ServiceStack.Auth.UserAuth' to type 'SOS.Api.ServiceModel.Types.User'.","
```

was thrown. I know i can extend registerservice.cs, but how do i use the customized .cs? in `AppHost.cs` `Plugins.Add(new RegistrationFeature());` or something? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ServiceStack's [RegisterService](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/main/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack/Auth/RegisterService.cs) is tied to the built-in `UserAuth` model, i.e:

```
[DefaultRequest(typeof(Register))]
public class RegisterService : RegisterUserAuthServiceBase {}
```

You would need to provide your own Custom Register Service to handle your Custom Poco which you can register with:

```
[DefaultRequest(typeof(Register))]
public class CustomRegisterService : RegisterUserAuthServiceBase {}
```

Since this is a different Register Service you don't want to enable ServiceStack's built-in [RegistrationFeature](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/main/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack/RegistrationFeature.cs):

```
//Plugins.Add(new RegistrationFeature()); //don't register this plugin
```

You should instead register your Service manually in your AppHost with:

```
this.RegisterService<CustomRegisterService>("/register");
this.RegisterAs<RegistrationValidator, IValidator<Register>>();
```

#### Use a modified copy

Since the [RegisterService](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/main/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack/Auth/RegisterService.cs) is fairly lightweight another option is to take a copy of it and modify it to reference your CustomUserAuth POCO instead.

Comment: Fantastic! Working like a charm.

Comment: I tried your code with ServiceStack 5.12.1 and now get the following error: `System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: 'Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
Could not load type 'ServiceStack.Auth.RegisterUserAuthServiceBase' from assembly 'ServiceStack, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.'` Do you maybe have any idea on how to fix this?